# Canceling a long-running function using an ISR

Tags: c, assembly, stack, microcontroller, interrupt

is there a way of manipulating the stack from a timer ISR? So i can just throw away the highest frame of the stack by forcing a long-running function to exit? (I am aware of loosing the heap-allocated memory in this case)

The target would probably be an ARM CPU.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you running a multithreading kernel?

Comment: I'd like to do it without multi-threading e.g. on a bare-metal machine or no threading support

Comment: Can the 'long-running function' 'register itself' for cancellation as it starts to run and 'unregister' itself just before returning?  Such actions whould allow the entry stack frame to be marked and made available to the ISR, (maybe:).  I don't like this plan, and I foresee lots of unforeseen problems:)

Comment: Note that this is a really good question.  I can't remember when I last upvoted a question on the C tag, usually it's a sea of downvotes:(

Comment: It will be useful to find which part of the function takes a long time. If it's a loop, then you can check a global variable as `break` condition. Then all your ISR needs to do is to set that global variable.

Comment: Don't do that. Understand that you want a multi-task scheduler. Then use a real multitasked kernel. Read also about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like [setjmp/longjmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) with longjmp called after ISR termination.

It is possible alter ISR return address such a way, that instead of returning to `long-running function` longjmp will be called with right parameters and `long-running function` will be aborted to the place where setjmp was called.

Just another solution came in mind. May be it would be easier to restore all the registers (Stack pointer, PC, LR and others) to values they have before `long-running functions` was called in the ISR stack frame (using assembly). In order to do that you need to save all required values (using assembly) before `long-running functions`.

Comment: is there some example or other sources?

Comment: @Stasik, There is a good setjmp/longjmp example [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~huangj/cs360/360/notes/Setjmp/lecture.html). ISR return address (PC, I think) should be modified in the stack frame using assembly. [Here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Babedgea.html) ARM M3 stack frame layout.

Comment: I am not too experienced in assembly, have you got some "entry points" like articles or other stuff?

Comment: @Stasik, here is [the articles](https://singpolyma.net/category/singpolyma-kernel/) I've found about writing simple OS kernel for ARM. There is a source for context switch routine (routine for switching stack, registers and another task-related stuff) on [github](https://github.com/singpolyma/singpolyma-kernel/blob/master/context_switch.s). If I found spare time, I can expand my answer more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend avoiding a long-running function. While it may work in the short term, as your code grows it could become problematic.

Instead, consider using a state machine, or system of state machines in your master loop, and using your ISR for a flag.  This will reduce timing issues and allow you to manage more tasks at once.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible in theory, but probably impossible to do reliably.

You could use GCC builtins `__builtin_frame_address` and `__builtin_return_address` to correctly restore the stack and return from the previous function, but it will corrupt the program behavior. The function you forcibly return probably saved some registers on the stack, and needed to restore them before returning. The problem is, there is no way I know of to locate or mimic the restore code. It is certainly located just before the function returns (and you can't even know where this is), but it could be 1, 2, or even 0 instructions. And even if you locate it or mimic it, you can't really hardcode it, because it is likely to change when you change the function.

In conclusion, you may be able if you use some builtins and 2-3 inline assembly instructions, but you need to tailor-hardcode it for the function you want to return, and you have to change it whenever you change the function.

Comment: Hmm.. a calling convention where the caller cleans up the stack might be useful?  This question is giving me a headache:(

Comment: Doesn't ARM use a separate stack for interrupts? In that case, `__builtin_frame_address` might not get the right stack.

Comment: @MartinJames Maybe a little, but it doesn't help the problem that callee-saved registers must be restored, and I don't know any convention that have no callee-saved registers. Also, the compiler doesn't expect this behavior, and often doesn't include stack cleaning even for caller cleaned conventions (because it thought, with reason, that it didn't have to).

Comment: @EOF Maybe, I didn't try, but `__builtin_frame_address` is said to support multiple call levels. Maybe ARM GCC take this into account on devices that have this behavior.

Comment: If it was me, I would probably use a tasker just to avoid having to attempt this.  The long-runner could be threaded off and the thread and both it and ISR would set a semaphore/event.  First there wins:)

Comment: @ElderBug cant i force the user to do a function "prelude" like if(1==0){return;}; and eventually only void functions. Giving it a "fixed" place in relation to the function's head?

Comment: @Stasik That would be an idea, but that won't work because it's not that simple. First, a `if(false) return;` will be optimized out by the compiler (even with -O0 in most cases), so the return code won't be here. Even if you get the compiler to not optimize this, you can't know in advance where this code will be in the function, because there may be a register saving at the beginning of the function, and maybe the return code will be merged with the end of the function, with a jump to the end instead of a return.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just set a flag in your isr that your function will periodically check to see if it needs to exit? The reason I disapprove of the way you are trying to do it is because it is extremely dangerous to "kill" a function when it is in the middle of some operation. Unless you have a way to clean up absolutely everything after it (like when killing a process) there is no other way you can do it safely. It is always better to signal the function through a flag or semaphore of some kind from isr and then let that function cleanup after itself and exit normally.